# Regex to validate alpahanumeric or a set of special characters

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a requirement to ensure that the string has only alphanumeric or a set of characters like + ( ) , ' . - =
I tried like

```
    String regex = "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([\\'|\\()|\\+|\\,|\\-|\\.|\\="]+)";
    System.out.println("Regex : " + regex);

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Match");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Matching");
    }
```

Bt it is not working, Can anyone help me please

Thanks in advance

Comment: Syntax colorization clearly shows that you have parenthesing problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it will not match a whole string containing a mix of alphanumerics and symbols because of the OR in the middle.

e.g. it wont match abcABC()+, but will match abcABC and will match ()+

Try:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9\\'\\(\\+\\)\\,\\-\\.\\=]+)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You should remove characters `|`. It is not a OR, it just means that you also match character `|`. I tested with `([a-zA-Z0-9\\'\\(\\+\\,\\-\\.\\=]+)`, it works.

Comment: Well spotted. I just did a bit of copy/paste from the question! :) Will update now.

Comment: Please also replace `\\()` with `\\(\\)`

Comment: @adenoyelle why you want to replace `\\()` with `\\(\\)`? In [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) they are not special characters. In this case only `-` needs escaping.

Comment: @user1407668 sorry but you said `only alphanumeric or a set of characters like + ( ) , ' . - =` so should `"ab.cd"` be matched or not?

Answer (score 3):

Use following regular expression:

```
^[-+=(),'.a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

If you want allow zero-length string, replace `+` with `*`:

```
^[-+=(),'.a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Comment: @Pshemo, That was intended, because OP wrote `.. ensure that the string has only alphanumeric or a set ..`.  Maybe I misunderstood. (I'm not good at reading English)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have compilation problem in

```
String regex = "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([\\'|\\()|\\+|\\,|\\-|\\.|\\="]+)";
```

because you have `"` before `]` which ends String. If you want to include `"` in that set of characters you need to escape it `\"`. If not then just remove it from your regex.

Also `|` inside `[...]` will make it normal character, not OR operator so you don't need to use it here. BTW only special character that need escaping in your `[...]` is `-`.

---

Try maybe

```
String regex = "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(['()+,\\-.=]+)";
```

or if you want to include `"` in special characters

```
String regex = "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(['()+,\\-.=\"]+)";
```